# Magnetic fields cause common mode noise

Tags: power-electronics, antenna, electromagnetism, emi-filtering

Here is the document that I am reading : 
https://www.emcfastpass.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/an15.pdf

And here is the assertion :

[image]

I understand that a current flowing through a trace which encircles a large physical area can radiate magnetic field. As the current varies in function of the time, the magnetic flux will also vary. So according to the Faraday's law, a voltage varying according to the magnetic flux will be induced accros the traces which see the fluctuating magnectic flux. I understand that it will produce common mode noise as there will be loop antenna between the line/neutral and the ground but why it will not produce differential mode noise as there will be a loop between the line and the neutral ? I read that the loop length have to be equal to the wavelength to have a perfect reception/transmission. So @ 1 MHz, it means a loop length of 300 meters ? So the difference is probably because the ground-line/neutral loop are larger than the neutral-line loop ? Isn't it ?

Thank you very much :D Have a nice day !

Comment: Read the preceding sentence in the highlighted text.

Comment: Actually, it is not very clear (at least to me). I understand that there is conducted differential mode noise which is due to the trapezoidal or triangular waveform. But there is no differential mode noise due to radiated emissions. But there is common mode noise due to radiated emissions.

Comment: It uses the word "emission" in that sentence @Jess.

Comment: Ok that's my fault so ! :D Thank you :D